# Excel Vba - Copy row number

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA and I'm trying to get a macro to look up the next empty row in a sheet and then copy the row number and then paste that value into another workbook.

This is as far as I've got.

```
Sub Retrieve_Row_Number ()

Dim erow As Integer

erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Workbooks.Open "\\hamfile\public\(P) Maintenance\MJR_Status.xlsm", ReadOnly
ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
```

I've seen the ActiveCell.Row function used with MsgBox to display the row number but I'd like to copy it so it can be used as a cell value pasted into the second sheet

If anyone can give me code to copy a row number of a selected row to the clipboard it would be hugely appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below code:

```
Sub RowAdd()

Dim eRow As Integer
ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Select
eRow = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Row
Workbooks.Open "\\hamfile\public\(P) Maintenance\MJR_Status.xlsm", ReadOnly
ActiveSheet.Cells(eRow, 1).Select

End Sub
```